# I accidently threw a money bag back up onto the train roof. What now?

Tags: payday-2

## I just really love throwing things, ok?  Don't judge me.

---

[image: I seem to have gotten a little excited with the toss button]

Now the money bag is stuck on the train roof and none of us can get it back down, even with fast hands.  **Is there anything we can do?**

Comment: This shouldn't be a well known problem actually, since no one would  throw it on there.

Comment: @Loko - I fibbed a little bit in the question.  I wasn't the one who tossed it up there, one of the other players did.  It was an accident, but it actually happened.

Comment: haha with all due respect but what the hell xd

Comment: The bag landed on the table.  I suspect he was trying to grab a painting, grabbed the bag instead, and tossed before he realized.

Comment: hah i know xd anyway good solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Toss a grenade up there.

Bags are physics objects and are affected by grenade blasts.  Gristle and Big Zam! both have grenades.  A grenade tossed in the train car directly underneath the bag will cause the bag to bounce into the air and off the train.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a shotgun with [HE Rounds](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Ammunition#HE_Round) (Update 31 / Gage Shotgun Pack DLC) equipped, shooting at the bags will also move them. In OP's case, one could shoot at the bag from inside the train, to move it to the side and off the train, or to the hatch at the train roof.